# How to customize the menu collapse?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have 2 menu collapse (one on the right and one on the left).

In the following file it is recommended that:

- if collapse-first is open, collapse-second is closed
- if collapse-second is open, collapse-first is closed
- if form-sumit is clicked, collapse-first is closed
- if form-sumit is clicked, collapse-second is closed

it works very well.

I want the last 2 lines to be more precise.

I want that :

```
  $('.form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });
```

only with form-sumit of #navbar-collapse-first

I want that:

```
  $('.form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  });
```

only with form-sumit of #navbar-collapse-second

```
(function ($) {

  $('#navbar-collapse-first').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  })

  $('#navbar-collapse-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  })

  $('.form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('.form-submit').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
  });

})(window.jQuery);
```